# Responsive grid has broken my js element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I had a nav bar that was programmed to roll onto screen on.click, and then roll back on.click again.

It was working beautifully, but now it is not working at all. I did convert the layout to 12 col grid for a fluid responsive design, but even when I set it back the other way now it still doesn't work.

Any help is always appreciated.

Here's the site: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev4/

And the mark up:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="dashboard">
            <nav id="access">
                <div class="open">Here's the Nav Bar
            </nav>
        </div> <!-- dashboard -->
    </div> <!-- span12 -->
</div> <!-- row-fluid -->
```

And the script:

```
$('.open').bind('click',function() { 
    $('#dashboard').stop().animate({
        right: $(this).hasClass('close') ? '-659px' : '0'
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
});
```

Now I assume it's the css that's causing the trouble, but I'm not sure where to look, just learning responsive design and I don't think it's helpful to dump my whole style sheet, but I'll try to pick out the relevant bits:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
}

body{
    min-height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.row-fluid .span12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.94680851063829%;
}

#access {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    width: 730px;
}

#dashboard {
   font-size: 30px;
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   right: -659px;
   z-index: 100;
}

.open {
   background: #cabd32 url(images/open.png) top left no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   float: left;
   padding: 32px 35px 33px;
}

.close {
   background: #cabd32 url(images/close.png) top left no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   float: left;
   padding: 32px 35px 33px;
}
```

Been picking at it for hours, to no avail, love some help.
cheers,

Comment: If you open developer tools and check the console you'll see that your theme's css is not loading, it's giving a 404, plus you have another error related to `jquery.easing`

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs those were extraneous so I didn't think they'd have any impact, but taking out the call to those scripts in the head fixed it. Have to start using my console!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.open').bind('click',function(){ 
    $('#dashboard').stop().animate(
    {
        right: $(this).hasClass('close') ? '-790px' : '0'
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
});
```

And change `dashboard` in **CSS**

```
#dashboard {
  font-size:30px;
  float:left;
  position: absolute;
  right: -790px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rohan, the issue seemed to fixed by removing the extraneous scripts in the head section. I don't see any difference between what you suggested and what is there now. Am I missing something?